# get file properties via dbus command

Tags: command-line, dbus

I want to get file properties via the dbus command.

I am quiet positive that the command is something like:

```
$ dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItemProperties
```

It is giving error `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Type of message, “()”, does not match expected type “(ass)”`. I do not have any idea what this argument should look like or where i can get it from.

To get the items, there is another command:

```
$ dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems
```

This also gives the same error.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ShowItemProperties` method takes two inputs according to  https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/file-manager-interface/

This would correlate with the error message you are getting of those inputs not being provided on the command line. The inputs required are an array of file paths and an id for the opened pop-up.

An example would be to show the properties of the `.bashrc` file in the home users directory:

```
filepath="$HOME/.bashrc"                                           
fileuri=$(echo $filepath | python -c "import sys, pathlib; print(pathlib.Path(input()).resolve().as_uri())")

dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItemProperties array:string:"$fileuri" string:""
```

for fish shell the script would be like:

```
set filepath "$HOME/.bashrc"

set fileuri $(echo $filepath | python -c "import sys, pathlib; print(pathlib.Path(input()).resolve().as_uri())")

dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItemProperties array:string:"$fileuri" string:""
```

**P.S.** If you do not convert file path to file uri then path like `$HOME/Desktop/directory with spaces and ümläuts.txt` will not work.

Comment: I think the command take a file uri and not a path. I mean the file identifier need to be like `file:///`. Please check your command output. Though it opens a window it shows size, type etc. as unknown.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail Thanks for spotting that. Example updated.

Comment: To convert file path to file uri https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/632198/206574 Your path worked coincidentally. I am accepting but please fix it.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme "A valid file URI must therefore begin with either file:/path (no hostname), file:///path (empty hostname), or file://hostname/path." so I think my path worked because it is a valid `no hostname` option. Happy for you to edit the answer if you want something specific.